# Creating a for loop which can filter and then perform a complex number of things

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am a basic user of R. I am trying to build a script which can automate some of my work in order to allow me to spend more time looking at the issues and resolving them, rather than spending time finding the issues.

I have a large dataframe called RawData. This has numerous entries for orders (orders of the same product, and other products). I want to take a product number and then catagorise the product into all its relevent areas that I am interested in testing.

I have tried to perform the code and I have it all working when I specify which product number I want to look at.

```
RawData[RawData$productID == "E1540",] -> E1540
```

What I want to be able to do is replace the E1540 with a value from a table, and then have it loop through all the values in the table, performing all the analysis, and then at the end, outputing the answer if it is relevent into a table I can then look at.

As I have all the code working for a one off product code, all I really want to know is how to perform a for loop based on a table of product codes I can set up (I think I can do this) so that it goes through each one, performs all the analysis, and then goes on to the next one after populating a table with the values.

(I end up further catagorising the product ID based on order type, payment type and customer base).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Cheers for the comments thus far. I will have a play then get back to you. From what I have read around the subject, and reading your answers I hope to have something.

Thanks, you are all stars.

UPDATE

What I am wanting my code to do is go through the list, create summations where all things are equal them do comparative analysis (Ab testing) to see if one is better than the other, spit out the result as a confidence percentage then do the next one.

I have got this far but have plenty more errors, a key one seems to be

> Error in if (Conversioncalcd >= 0) { :    missing value where
>   TRUE/FALSE needed

```
#Create a dataframe to store the results
AB_Product_results <- data.frame(50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50)
colnames(AB_Product_results)[1] <-"Product ID"
colnames(AB_Product_results)[2] <-"Mobile"
colnames(AB_Product_results)[3] <-"desktop"
colnames(AB_Product_results)[4] <-"Tablet"
colnames(AB_Product_results)[5] <-"Mobile and Tablet"
colnames(AB_Product_results)[6] <-"Mobile Existing users"
colnames(AB_Product_results)[7] <-"desktop Existing users"
colnames(AB_Product_results)[8] <-"Tablet Existing users"
colnames(AB_Product_results)[9] <-"Mobile and Tablet Existing users"
colnames(AB_Product_results)[10] <-"Mobile New users"
colnames(AB_Product_results)[11] <-"desktop New users"
colnames(AB_Product_results)[12] <-"Tablet New users"
colnames(AB_Product_results)[13] <-"Mobile and Tablet New users"

#Find the AB test results
RawData[RawData$test_type =="AB",] -> ABtests

#obtain a list of productal ID's which are unique (one ID per product)
list_of_ABproduct_ids <- unique(ABtests$atg_test_id)

#this is the for loop which goes through the list and does the analysis
  results <- sapply(list_of_ABproduct_ids, function(products){
    ABproductsData <- ABtests[ABtests$atg_test_id == products,]

    # The analysis begins here.
    # first split control and challenger
    ABproductsData[ABproductsData$version_desc =="control",] -> control
    ABproductsData[ABproductsData$version_desc =="challenger",] -> challenger

    # Split into device for the control
    control[control$device == "M",] -> controlm
    control[control$device == "D",] -> controld
    control[control$device == "T",] -> controlt
    control[control$device != "M",] -> controldt

    #split into device for the challenger
    challenger[challenger$device == "M",] -> challengerm
    challenger[challenger$device == "D",] -> challengerd
    challenger[challenger$device == "T",] -> challengert
    challenger[challenger$device != "M",] -> challengerdt

    #split into user groups
    #first existing
    controlm[controlm$kpi_group == "EX",] -> controlmEX
    controld[controld$kpi_group == "EX",] -> controldEX
    controlt[controlt$kpi_group == "EX",] -> controltEX
    controldt[controldt$kpi_group == "EX",] -> controldtEX

    challengerm[challengerm$kpi_group == "EX",] -> challengermEX
    challengerd[challengerd$kpi_group == "EX",] -> challengerdEX
    challengert[challengert$kpi_group == "EX",] -> challengertEX
    challengerdt[challengerdt$kpi_group == "EX",] -> challengerdtEX

    # split for new users
    controlm[controlm$kpi_group == "NW",] -> controlmNW
    controld[controld$kpi_group == "NW",] -> controldNW
    controlt[controlt$kpi_group == "NW",] -> controltNW
    controldt[controldt$kpi_group == "NW",] -> controldtNW

    challengerm[challengerm$kpi_group == "NW",] -> challengermNW
    challengerd[challengerd$kpi_group == "NW",] -> challengerdNW
    challengert[challengert$kpi_group == "NW",] -> challengertNW
    challengerdt[challengerdt$kpi_group == "NW",] -> challengerdtNW

    #aggregate the results prior to testing
    #control
    #aggregate based on device only
    aggregate(cbind(visits, visitors, orderers, pages, orders, items, Cash)~goal_name,data=controlm,FUN=sum) -> controlmsum
    aggregate(cbind(visits, visitors, orderers, pages, orders, items, Cash)~goal_name,data=controld,FUN=sum) -> controldsum
    aggregate(cbind(visits, visitors, orderers, pages, orders, items, Cash)~goal_name,data=controlt,FUN=sum) -> controltsum
    aggregate(cbind(visits, visitors, orderers, pages, orders, items, Cash)~goal_name,data=controldt,FUN=sum) -> controldtsum

    #aggregate based on device and existing user
    aggregate(cbind(visits, visitors, orderers, pages, orders, items, Cash)~goal_name,data=controlmEX,FUN=sum) -> controlmEXsum
    aggregate(cbind(visits, visitors, orderers, pages, orders, items, Cash)~goal_name,data=controldEX,FUN=sum) -> controldEXsum
    aggregate(cbind(visits, visitors, orderers, pages, orders, items, Cash)~goal_name,data=controltEX,FUN=sum) -> controltEXsum
    aggregate(cbind(visits, visitors, orderers, pages, orders, items, Cash)~goal_name,data=controldtEX,FUN=sum) -> controldtEXsum

    #aggregate based on device and new user
    aggregate(cbind(visits, visitors, orderers, pages, orders, items, Cash)~goal_name,data=controlmNW,FUN=sum) -> controlmNWsum
    aggregate(cbind(visits, visitors, orderers, pages, orders, items, Cash)~goal_name,data=controldNW,FUN=sum) -> controldNWsum
    aggregate(cbind(visits, visitors, orderers, pages, orders, items, Cash)~goal_name,data=controltNW,FUN=sum) -> controltNWsum
    aggregate(cbind(visits, visitors, orderers, pages, orders, items, Cash)~goal_name,data=controldtNW,FUN=sum) -> controldtNWsum

    #challenger
    #aggregate based on device only
    aggregate(cbind(visits, visitors, orderers, pages, orders, items, Cash)~goal_name,data=challengerm,FUN=sum) -> challengermsum
    aggregate(cbind(visits, visitors, orderers, pages, orders, items, Cash)~goal_name,data=challengerd,FUN=sum) -> challengerdsum
    aggregate(cbind(visits, visitors, orderers, pages, orders, items, Cash)~goal_name,data=challengert,FUN=sum) -> challengertsum
    aggregate(cbind(visits, visitors, orderers, pages, orders, items, Cash)~goal_name,data=challengerdt,FUN=sum) -> challengerdtsum

    #aggregate based on device and existing user
    aggregate(cbind(visits, visitors, orderers, pages, orders, items, Cash)~goal_name,data=challengermEX,FUN=sum) -> challengermEXsum
    aggregate(cbind(visits, visitors, orderers, pages, orders, items, Cash)~goal_name,data=challengerdEX,FUN=sum) -> challengerdEXsum
    aggregate(cbind(visits, visitors, orderers, pages, orders, items, Cash)~goal_name,data=challengertEX,FUN=sum) -> challengertEXsum
    aggregate(cbind(visits, visitors, orderers, pages, orders, items, Cash)~goal_name,data=challengerdtEX,FUN=sum) -> challengerdtEXsum

    #aggregate based on device and new user
    aggregate(cbind(visits, visitors, orderers, pages, orders, items, Cash)~goal_name,data=challengermNW,FUN=sum) -> challengermNWsum
    aggregate(cbind(visits, visitors, orderers, pages, orders, items, Cash)~goal_name,data=challengerdNW,FUN=sum) -> challengerdNWsum
    aggregate(cbind(visits, visitors, orderers, pages, orders, items, Cash)~goal_name,data=challengertNW,FUN=sum) -> challengertNWsum
    aggregate(cbind(visits, visitors, orderers, pages, orders, items, Cash)~goal_name,data=challengerdtNW,FUN=sum) -> challengerdtNWsum

    #calculate conversion for all
    controlmsum$orders / controlmsum$visitors -> Conversioncontrolm
    controldsum$orders / controldsum$visitors -> Conversioncontrold
    controltsum$orders / controltsum$visitors -> Conversioncontrolt
    controldtsum$orders / controldtsum$visitors -> Conversioncontroldt
    controlmEXsum$orders / controlmEXsum$visitors -> ConversioncontrolmEX
    controldEXsum$orders / controldEXsum$visitors -> ConversioncontroldEX
    controltEXsum$orders / controltEXsum$visitors -> ConversioncontroltEX
    controldtEXsum$orders / controldtEXsum$visitors -> ConversioncontroldtEX
    controlmNWsum$orders / controlmNWsum$visitors -> ConversioncontrolmNW
    controldNWsum$orders / controldNWsum$visitors -> ConversioncontroldNW
    controltNWsum$orders / controltNWsum$visitors -> ConversioncontroltNW
    controldtNWsum$orders / controldtNWsum$visitors -> ConversioncontroldtNW

    challengermsum$orders / challengermsum$visitors -> Conversionchallengerm
    challengerdsum$orders / challengerdsum$visitors -> Conversionchallengerd
    challengertsum$orders / challengertsum$visitors -> Conversionchallengert
    challengerdtsum$orders / challengerdtsum$visitors -> Conversionchallengerdt
    challengermEXsum$orders / challengermEXsum$visitors -> ConversionchallengermEX
    challengerdEXsum$orders / challengerdEXsum$visitors -> ConversionchallengerdEX
    challengertEXsum$orders / challengertEXsum$visitors -> ConversionchallengertEX
    challengerdtEXsum$orders / challengerdtEXsum$visitors -> ConversionchallengerdtEX
    challengermNWsum$orders / challengermNWsum$visitors -> ConversionchallengermNW
    challengerdNWsum$orders / challengerdNWsum$visitors -> ConversionchallengerdNW
    challengertNWsum$orders / challengertNWsum$visitors -> ConversionchallengertNW
    challengerdtNWsum$orders / challengerdtNWsum$visitors -> ConversionchallengerdtNW

    #calculate conversion
    Conversioncalcm <- (Conversionchallengerm-Conversioncontrolm)/sqrt((Conversionchallengerm*(1-Conversionchallengerm))/challengermsum$visitors+(Conversioncontrolm*(1-Conversioncontrolm))/controlmsum$visitors)
    Conversioncalcd <- (Conversionchallengerd-Conversioncontrold)/sqrt((Conversionchallengerd*(1-Conversionchallengerd))/challengerdsum$visitors+(Conversioncontrold*(1-Conversioncontrold))/controldsum$visitors)
    Conversioncalct <- (Conversionchallengert-Conversioncontrolt)/sqrt((Conversionchallengert*(1-Conversionchallengert))/challengertsum$visitors+(Conversioncontrolt*(1-Conversioncontrolt))/controltsum$visitors)
    Conversioncalcdt <- (Conversionchallengerdt-Conversioncontroldt)/sqrt((Conversionchallengerdt*(1-Conversionchallengerdt))/challengerdtsum$visitors+(Conversioncontroldt*(1-Conversioncontroldt))/controldtsum$visitors)

    ConversioncalcmEX <- (ConversionchallengermEX-ConversioncontrolmEX)/sqrt((ConversionchallengermEX*(1-ConversionchallengermEX))/challengermEXsum$visitors+(ConversioncontrolmEX*(1-ConversioncontrolmEX))/controlmEXsum$visitors)
    ConversioncalcdEX <- (ConversionchallengerdEX-ConversioncontroldEX)/sqrt((ConversionchallengerdEX*(1-ConversionchallengerdEX))/challengerdEXsum$visitors+(ConversioncontroldEX*(1-ConversioncontroldEX))/controldEXsum$visitors)
    ConversioncalctEX <- (ConversionchallengertEX-ConversioncontroltEX)/sqrt((ConversionchallengertEX*(1-ConversionchallengertEX))/challengertEXsum$visitors+(ConversioncontroltEX*(1-ConversioncontroltEX))/controltEXsum$visitors)
    ConversioncalcdtEX <- (ConversionchallengerdtEX-ConversioncontroldtEX)/sqrt((ConversionchallengerdtEX*(1-ConversionchallengerdtEX))/challengerdtEXsum$visitors+(ConversioncontroldtEX*(1-ConversioncontroldtEX))/controldtEXsum$visitors)

    ConversioncalcmNW <- (ConversionchallengermNW-ConversioncontrolmNW)/sqrt((ConversionchallengermNW*(1-ConversionchallengermNW))/challengermNWsum$visitors+(ConversioncontrolmNW*(1-ConversioncontrolmNW))/controlmNWsum$visitors)
    ConversioncalcdNW <- (ConversionchallengerdNW-ConversioncontroldNW)/sqrt((ConversionchallengerdNW*(1-ConversionchallengerdNW))/challengerdNWsum$visitors+(ConversioncontroldNW*(1-ConversioncontroldNW))/controldNWsum$visitors)
    ConversioncalctNW <- (ConversionchallengertNW-ConversioncontroltNW)/sqrt((ConversionchallengertNW*(1-ConversionchallengertNW))/challengertNWsum$visitors+(ConversioncontroltNW*(1-ConversioncontroltNW))/controltNWsum$visitors)
    ConversioncalcdtNW <- (ConversionchallengerdtNW-ConversioncontroldtNW)/sqrt((ConversionchallengerdtNW*(1-ConversionchallengerdtNW))/challengerdtNWsum$visitors+(ConversioncontroldtNW*(1-ConversioncontroldtNW))/controldtNWsum$visitors)

    #calculate the confidence limits
    Confidencelimit1m <- 1-0.39894228*exp(-1*Conversioncalcm * Conversioncalcm/2)*(1/(1+0.2316419 * Conversioncalcm)) * ((1/(1+0.2316419 * Conversioncalcm))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * Conversioncalcm))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * Conversioncalcm))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * Conversioncalcm))*1.330274429+-1.821255978)+1.781477937)+-0.356563782)+0.31938153)

    Confidencelimit2m <-(0.39894228*exp(-1* Conversioncalcm * Conversioncalcm/2)*(1/(1-0.2316419* Conversioncalcm))*((1/(1-0.2316419* Conversioncalcm))*((1/(1-0.2316419* Conversioncalcm))*((1/(1-0.2316419 * Conversioncalcm))*((1/(1-0.2316419* Conversioncalcm))*1.330274429+-1.821255978)+1.781477937)+-0.356563782)+0.31938153))

    if(Conversioncalcm>=0) {
      Confidencelimitm <- Confidencelimit1m
    } else {
      Confidencelimitm <- Confidencelimit2m
    }

    Confidencelimit1d <- 1-0.39894228*exp(-1*Conversioncalcd * Conversioncalcd/2)*(1/(1+0.2316419 * Conversioncalcd)) * ((1/(1+0.2316419 * Conversioncalcd))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * Conversioncalcd))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * Conversioncalcd))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * Conversioncalcd))*1.330274429+-1.821255978)+1.781477937)+-0.356563782)+0.31938153)

    Confidencelimit2d <-(0.39894228*exp(-1* Conversioncalcd * Conversioncalcd/2)*(1/(1-0.2316419* Conversioncalcd))*((1/(1-0.2316419* Conversioncalcd))*((1/(1-0.2316419* Conversioncalcd))*((1/(1-0.2316419 * Conversioncalcd))*((1/(1-0.2316419* Conversioncalcd))*1.330274429+-1.821255978)+1.781477937)+-0.356563782)+0.31938153))

    if(Conversioncalcd>=0) {
      Confidencelimitd = Confidencelimit1d
    } else {
      Confidencelimitd = Confidencelimit2d
    }

    Confidencelimit1t <- 1-0.39894228*exp(-1*Conversioncalct * Conversioncalct/2)*(1/(1+0.2316419 * Conversioncalct)) * ((1/(1+0.2316419 * Conversioncalct))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * Conversioncalct))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * Conversioncalct))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * Conversioncalct))*1.330274429+-1.821255978)+1.781477937)+-0.356563782)+0.31938153)

    Confidencelimit2t <-(0.39894228*exp(-1* Conversioncalct * Conversioncalct/2)*(1/(1-0.2316419* Conversioncalct))*((1/(1-0.2316419* Conversioncalct))*((1/(1-0.2316419* Conversioncalct))*((1/(1-0.2316419 * Conversioncalct))*((1/(1-0.2316419* Conversioncalct))*1.330274429+-1.821255978)+1.781477937)+-0.356563782)+0.31938153))

    if(Conversioncalct>=0) {
      Confidencelimitt <- Confidencelimit1t
    } else {
      Confidencelimitt <- Confidencelimit2t
    }

    Confidencelimit1dt <- 1-0.39894228*exp(-1*Conversioncalcdt * Conversioncalcdt/2)*(1/(1+0.2316419 * Conversioncalcdt)) * ((1/(1+0.2316419 * Conversioncalcdt))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * Conversioncalcdt))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * Conversioncalcdt))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * Conversioncalcdt))*1.330274429+-1.821255978)+1.781477937)+-0.356563782)+0.31938153)

    Confidencelimit2dt <-(0.39894228*exp(-1* Conversioncalcdt * Conversioncalcdt/2)*(1/(1-0.2316419* Conversioncalcdt))*((1/(1-0.2316419* Conversioncalcdt))*((1/(1-0.2316419* Conversioncalcdt))*((1/(1-0.2316419 * Conversioncalcdt))*((1/(1-0.2316419* Conversioncalcdt))*1.330274429+-1.821255978)+1.781477937)+-0.356563782)+0.31938153))

    if(Conversioncalcdt>=0) {
      Confidencelimitdt <- Confidencelimit1dt
    } else {
      Confidencelimitdt <- Confidencelimit2dt
    }

    Confidencelimit1mEX <- 1-0.39894228*exp(-1*ConversioncalcmEX * ConversioncalcmEX/2)*(1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcmEX)) * ((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcmEX))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcmEX))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcmEX))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcmEX))*1.330274429+-1.821255978)+1.781477937)+-0.356563782)+0.31938153)

    Confidencelimit2mEX <-(0.39894228*exp(-1* ConversioncalcmEX * ConversioncalcmEX/2)*(1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalcmEX))*((1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalcmEX))*((1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalcmEX))*((1/(1-0.2316419 * ConversioncalcmEX))*((1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalcmEX))*1.330274429+-1.821255978)+1.781477937)+-0.356563782)+0.31938153))

    if(ConversioncalcmEX>=0) {
      ConfidencelimitmEX <- Confidencelimit1mEX
    } else {
      ConfidencelimitmEX <- Confidencelimit2mEX
    }

    Confidencelimit1dEX <- 1-0.39894228*exp(-1*ConversioncalcdEX * ConversioncalcdEX/2)*(1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcdEX)) * ((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcdEX))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcdEX))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcdEX))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcdEX))*1.330274429+-1.821255978)+1.781477937)+-0.356563782)+0.31938153)

    Confidencelimit2dEX <-(0.39894228*exp(-1* ConversioncalcdEX * ConversioncalcdEX/2)*(1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalcdEX))*((1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalcdEX))*((1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalcdEX))*((1/(1-0.2316419 * ConversioncalcdEX))*((1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalcdEX))*1.330274429+-1.821255978)+1.781477937)+-0.356563782)+0.31938153))

    if(ConversioncalcdEX>=0) {
      ConfidencelimitdEX <- Confidencelimit1dEX
    } else {
      ConfidencelimitdEX <- Confidencelimit2dEX
    }

    Confidencelimit1tEX <- 1-0.39894228*exp(-1*ConversioncalctEX * ConversioncalctEX/2)*(1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalctEX)) * ((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalctEX))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalctEX))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalctEX))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalctEX))*1.330274429+-1.821255978)+1.781477937)+-0.356563782)+0.31938153)

    Confidencelimit2tEX <-(0.39894228*exp(-1* ConversioncalctEX * ConversioncalctEX/2)*(1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalctEX))*((1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalctEX))*((1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalctEX))*((1/(1-0.2316419 * ConversioncalctEX))*((1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalctEX))*1.330274429+-1.821255978)+1.781477937)+-0.356563782)+0.31938153))

    if(ConversioncalctEX>=0) {
      ConfidencelimittEX <- Confidencelimit1tEX
    } else {
      ConfidencelimittEX <- Confidencelimit2tEX
    }

    Confidencelimit1dtEX <- 1-0.39894228*exp(-1*ConversioncalcdtEX * ConversioncalcdtEX/2)*(1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcdtEX)) * ((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcdtEX))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcdtEX))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcdtEX))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcdtEX))*1.330274429+-1.821255978)+1.781477937)+-0.356563782)+0.31938153)

    Confidencelimit2dtEX <-(0.39894228*exp(-1* ConversioncalcdtEX * ConversioncalcdtEX/2)*(1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalcdtEX))*((1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalcdtEX))*((1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalcdtEX))*((1/(1-0.2316419 * ConversioncalcdtEX))*((1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalcdtEX))*1.330274429+-1.821255978)+1.781477937)+-0.356563782)+0.31938153))

    if(ConversioncalcdtEX>=0) {
      ConfidencelimitdtEX <- Confidencelimit1dtEX 
    } else {
      ConfidencelimitdtEX <- Confidencelimit2dtEX 
    }

    Confidencelimit1mNW <- 1-0.39894228*exp(-1*ConversioncalcmNW * ConversioncalcmNW/2)*(1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcmNW)) * ((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcmNW))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcmNW))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcmNW))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcmNW))*1.330274429+-1.821255978)+1.781477937)+-0.356563782)+0.31938153)

    Confidencelimit2mNW <-(0.39894228*exp(-1* ConversioncalcmNW * ConversioncalcmNW/2)*(1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalcmNW))*((1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalcmNW))*((1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalcmNW))*((1/(1-0.2316419 * ConversioncalcmNW))*((1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalcmNW))*1.330274429+-1.821255978)+1.781477937)+-0.356563782)+0.31938153))

    if(ConversioncalcmNW>=0) {
      ConfidencelimitmNW <- Confidencelimit1mNW
    } else {
      ConfidencelimitmNW <- Confidencelimit2mNW
    }

    Confidencelimit1dNW <- 1-0.39894228*exp(-1*ConversioncalcdNW * ConversioncalcdNW/2)*(1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcdNW)) * ((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcdNW))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcdNW))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcdNW))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcdNW))*1.330274429+-1.821255978)+1.781477937)+-0.356563782)+0.31938153)

    Confidencelimit2dNW <-(0.39894228*exp(-1* ConversioncalcdNW * ConversioncalcdNW/2)*(1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalcdNW))*((1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalcdNW))*((1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalcdNW))*((1/(1-0.2316419 * ConversioncalcdNW))*((1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalcdNW))*1.330274429+-1.821255978)+1.781477937)+-0.356563782)+0.31938153))

    if(ConversioncalcdNW>=0) {
      ConfidencelimitdNW <- Confidencelimit1dNW
    } else {
      ConfidencelimitdNW <- Confidencelimit2dNW
    }


    Confidencelimit1tNW <- 1-0.39894228*exp(-1*ConversioncalctNW * ConversioncalctNW/2)*(1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalctNW)) * ((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalctNW))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalctNW))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalctNW))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalctNW))*1.330274429+-1.821255978)+1.781477937)+-0.356563782)+0.31938153)

    Confidencelimit2tNW <-(0.39894228*exp(-1* ConversioncalctNW * ConversioncalctNW/2)*(1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalctNW))*((1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalctNW))*((1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalctNW))*((1/(1-0.2316419 * ConversioncalctNW))*((1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalctNW))*1.330274429+-1.821255978)+1.781477937)+-0.356563782)+0.31938153))

    if(ConversioncalctNW>=0) {
      ConfidencelimittNW <- Confidencelimit1tNW 
    } else {
      ConfidencelimittNW <- Confidencelimit2tNW 
    }

    Confidencelimit1dtNW <- 1-0.39894228*exp(-1*ConversioncalcdtNW * ConversioncalcdtNW/2)*(1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcdtNW)) * ((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcdtNW))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcdtNW))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcdtNW))*((1/(1+0.2316419 * ConversioncalcdtNW))*1.330274429+-1.821255978)+1.781477937)+-0.356563782)+0.31938153)

    Confidencelimit2dtNW <-(0.39894228*exp(-1* ConversioncalcdtNW * ConversioncalcdtNW/2)*(1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalcdtNW))*((1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalcdtNW))*((1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalcdtNW))*((1/(1-0.2316419 * ConversioncalcdtNW))*((1/(1-0.2316419* ConversioncalcdtNW))*1.330274429+-1.821255978)+1.781477937)+-0.356563782)+0.31938153))

    if(ConversioncalcdtNW>=0) {
      ConfidencelimitdtNW <- Confidencelimit1dtNW 
    } else {
      ConfidencelimitdtNW <- Confidencelimit2dtNW 
    }

    AB_Product_results_addition <- data.frame(products,Confidencelimitm,Confidencelimitd,Confidencelimitt,Confidencelimitdt,ConfidencelimitmEX,ConfidencelimitdEX,ConfidencelimittEX,ConfidencelimitdtEX,ConfidencelimitmNW,ConfidencelimitdNW,ConfidencelimittNW,ConfidencelimitdtNW)

    colnames(AB_Product_results_addition)[1] <-"Product ID"
    colnames(AB_Product_results_addition)[2] <-"Mobile"
    colnames(AB_Product_results_addition)[3] <-"Desktop"
    colnames(AB_Product_results_addition)[4] <-"Tablet"
    colnames(AB_Product_results_addition)[5] <-"Desktop and Tablet"
    colnames(AB_Product_results_addition)[6] <-"Mobile Existing users"
    colnames(AB_Product_results_addition)[7] <-"Desktop Existing users"
    colnames(AB_Product_results_addition)[8] <-"Tablet Existing users"
    colnames(AB_Product_results_addition)[9] <-"Desktop and Tablet Existing users"
    colnames(AB_Product_results_addition)[10] <-"Mobile New users"
    colnames(AB_Product_results_addition)[11] <-"Desktop New users"
    colnames(AB_Product_results_addition)[12] <-"Tablet New users"
    colnames(AB_Product_results_addition)[13] <-"Desktop and Tablet New users"

    return(AB_Product_results)
  })
```

Comment: It seems to me you are trying to match subsets of your data by productID? Have a look at `match` or `%in%`

Comment: could you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: Most of what you describe can be automated, but we would need to see a specific example to precisely tell you how to do it. Take a look at packages `data.table` or `dplyr` for efficient methods how to run a set of functions for subsets defined by the values of a variable in your data.

Comment: My code is now added to the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand it, you are looking for `sapply`. You need to specify a list of product id's, e.g.

```
list_of_product_ids <- unique(RawData$productID)
```

Then you can use sapply:

```
results <- sapply(list_of_product_ids, function(product){
  ProductData <- RawData[RawData$productID == product,]
  # perform some analysis here. 
  return(product_results)
})
```

Replace "# perform some analysis" by any analysis you would like to do, based on the ProductData and then save the results in product_results. This returns a list containing the results for each of your products. If the product_results are all of the same length, it returns a data.frame with one line for each product.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way how to achieve the result you are looking for. There are other options as weel

```
IDs <- unique(RawData$productID)

for (ID in IDs) {
  dat <- RawData[RawData$productID == ID, ]
  # Do your analyses with dat here
}
```